# Fall in confusing about binomial distribution... really need help please.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am wondering that whether binomial distribution can be expressed as conditional probability. For example, is equation $P_{X\mid N}(x)=\Pr(X=x\mid N=n)$ where variable $X$ is number of successful trials and $N$ is number of total trials correct? In my text book, binomial distribution is expressed as conditional probability. Please see image bellow,
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzIiH.png). They have $P(X_1=i, X_2=j\mid X=i+j)=\begin{pmatrix}{i+j}\\i\\ \end{pmatrix}p^i(1-p)^j$. Does this mean $P_{X\mid N}(x)=Pr(X=x\mid N=n)$ is correct? I know this question is somehow pointless, but I really hope to know.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson-distributed random variables with respective expected values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X+Y$ is a binomial distribution with parameters $X+Y$ and $\dfrac \alpha {\alpha+\beta}$.